# Android RecyclerView Detect context menu closed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, contextmenu

When the context menu is closed by pressing the backbutton in a recycler view,i want to update the recycler view's ui.
Overriding the back button in the activity hasn't helped.Any ideas are welcome

Comment: you can try with `onContextMenuClosed` in your `Activity`

Comment: In a recycler view , you implement it as a listener, and there you don't have that method to override

Comment: you were right :) ! had to register the recycler view  and had to override the onContextMenuClosed method in the activity with the listener in the recycler view.Makes sense now!

Comment: happy to know :) @yash sachdeva